# ¿Cómo hacer un segmento?

Tags: c++, matrices, dev-c++

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual deberia mostrar los * desde la coordenada (12,2) hasta (25, 75). Sin embargo, se queda a la mitad:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main (){

int x1 = 12;
int y1 = 2;
int x2 = 25;
int y2 = 75;

char segmento [x2+1][y2+1];

for (int i = 0; i < x2 + 1; i++ ){
    for (int j = 0; j < y2 + 1; j++){
        segmento [i][j] = '-';
    }
}

int tempo = y1; 
int mid;
for (int i = x1; i < x2 + 1; i++){
    mid = ( (y2 / i)) + tempo;   
    for (int j = tempo; j < mid; j++){
         segmento [i] [j] = '*';
         tempo ++; 
    }
}




for (int i = 0; i < x2 + 1; i++ ){
    cout << setw(2) << i;
    for (int j = 0; j < y2 + 1; j++){
        cout << segmento [i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo personalmente, cuando no se hacer algo, pero es evidente que ya otros muchos lo han tenido que hacer antes que yo... seguro que hay uno o varios algoritmos de renombre que se encargan de resolver el problema desde distintos enfoques, así que implico el tiempo más en buscar el algoritmo que en intentar desarrollarlo.

Con el tema de la representación de segmentos tenemos varios algoritmos que ya han resuelto ese problema. Uno de ellos es el [Algoritmo de Bresenham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bresenham)

Incluyo en tu código una implementación de éste algoritmo para que veas como funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int x1 = 12;
    int y1 = 2;

    int x2 = 25;
    int y2 = 75;

    char segmento [x2+1][y2+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < x2 + 1; i++ )
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < y2 + 1; j++)
      {
          segmento [i][j] = '-';
      }
    }

    // Aquí comienza la implementación del algoritmo

    // Distancia de desplazamiento en cada eje
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int incYi, incXi;
    int incYr, incXr;

    // Determinación del tipo de incremento en cada eje
    // positivo o negativo. Avance inclinado.

    if ( dy >= 0 )
    {
        incYi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dy = -dy; 
        incYi = -1;
    }

    if (dx >= 0)
    {
       incXi = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dx = -dx; 
        incXi = -1;
    }

    // Determinación del tipo de incremento en cada eje
    // positivo o negativo. Avance recto.

    if ( dx >= dy )
    {
        incYr = 0;
        incXr = incXi;
    }
    else
    {
        incXr = 0;
        incYr = incYi;
        // Si dy > dx las intercambiamos para reutilizar el bucle
        int tmp = dx; dx = dy; dy = tmp;

    }


    // Inicializamos
    int x = x1;
    int y = y1;

    int avR = 2 * dy;
    int av = avR - dx;
    int avI = av - dx;

    do
    {
        segmento[x][y] = '*';
        if (av >= 0)
        {
            x = x + incXi;
            y = y + incYi;
            av = av + avI;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x + incXr;
            y = y + incYr;
            av = av + avR;
        }
    }
    while(y != y2);

   // Aquí termina la implementación del algoritmo y continúa tu programa
      for (int i = 0; i < x2 + 1; i++ )
      {
          cout << setw(2) << i;
          for (int j = 0; j < y2 + 1; j++)
          {
              cout << segmento [i][j];
          }
          cout << "\n";
      }
  }
```

La salida sería:

```
 0----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 6----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 8----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9----------------------------------------------------------------------------
10----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12--***-----------------------------------------------------------------------
13-----******-----------------------------------------------------------------
14-----------******-----------------------------------------------------------
15-----------------*****------------------------------------------------------
16----------------------******------------------------------------------------
17----------------------------*****-------------------------------------------
18---------------------------------******-------------------------------------
19---------------------------------------******-------------------------------
20---------------------------------------------*****--------------------------
21--------------------------------------------------******--------------------
22--------------------------------------------------------*****---------------
23-------------------------------------------------------------******---------
24-------------------------------------------------------------------******---
25-------------------------------------------------------------------------**-
```

Comment: He leido que C soporta VLA, pero c++ no.

Answer (score 2):

Este array:

```
char segmento [x2+1][y2+1];
```

se conoce como VLA (Variable Lentgh Array) y no es un elemento soportado por el estándar de C++. Es un VLA porque su tamaño está basado en variables... y resulta que en C++ el tamaño de este tipo de arrays debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación.

Podrías pensar que los valores ya se conocen. Al fin y al cabo inicializas las variables:

```
int x1 = 12;
int y1 = 2;
int x2 = 25;
int y2 = 75;
```

Pero tengo malas noticias... son variables y el compilador no tiene por qué evaluarlas para determinar el tamaño del array.

Puedes hacerlas constantes con `const`:

```
const int x1 = 12;
const int y1 = 2;
const int x2 = 25;
const int y2 = 75;
```

O, a partir de C++11, también con `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int x1 = 12;
constexpr int y1 = 2;
constexpr int x2 = 25;
constexpr int y2 = 75;
```

Comment: No obstante... en gcc (8.2.1) ese código no da error de compilación. :-?

Comment: @Neoniet gcc soporta los VLAs.

Comment: @Neoniet no da error de compilación pero si un warning. Si esa característica no fuese peligrosa no mostraría dicha advertencia

Comment: @eferion ya ya si lo que me estraña es que no diera error, pero bueno será porqué en ese caso es predecible... digo yo. Por dar no me daba ni warning. Lo volveré a comprobar de todas formas ;-)